# Purpose of line : source ~oracle/.bash_profile in shell script

Tags: bash, scripting

While executing a shell script involving database connection, my script showed me an Error :sqlplus not found :

```
sqlplus -s username/paswd@DB_name  > /home/user/sql.out << EOF
```

But when i included the following statement, it started to work:

```
source ~oracle/.bash_profile
```

What is the purpose of this above line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This includes `~oracle/.bash_profile`in the script where the line `source  ~oracle/.bash_profile` is.

In your case it probably add the directory of Oracle bin in your PATH.

see also [source/dot man page](http://ss64.com/bash/period.html)

Answer (score 1):

That line includes the referenced shell script (in this case the `.bash_profile` from the Oracle home directory).

It's a simple means of decomposing shell scripts into smaller components and thus enabling reuse.